# Bash — [: too many arguments

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
# portcheck tool

usage()
{
    echo -e "\n USAGE: ./${0##*/} [host|ip] \n"
    exit
}

check_port()
{
    local host=${1}
    local port=${2}
    if [ nc -w 5 -z host port ] &&  [ nc -w 5 -z host port ]
    then
    echo -e "\a\n => Port ${port} at ${host} is open"
    else
    echo -e "\a\n => Port ${port} at ${host} is closed"
    fi
}

[[ $# -ne 2 ]] && usage

check_port ${1} ${2}
```

When I run the following command:

```
bash portOpenBash.sh 127.0.0.1 434
```

I get the following error:

```
portOpenBash.sh: line 14: [: too many arguments
```

I try to put quotes between the macro expression, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be in your `if` conditions here:

```
 if [ nc -w 5 -z host port ] &&  [ nc -w 5 -z host port ]
```

You probably want to check for non empty output of both commands like this:

```
if [ -n "$(nc -w 5 -z $host $port)" ] && [ -n "$(nc -w 5 -z $host $port)" ]
```

OR in BASH:

```
if [[ -n "$(nc -w 5 -z $host $port)" && -n "$(nc -w 5 -z $host $port)" ]]
```

**EDIT:**

OR else if you just want to check return codes then remove surrounding `[` and `]`:

```
 if nc -w 5 -z $host $port && nc -w 5 -z $host $port
```

Comment: I would guess he wants return code checking for those `nc` commands actually. So `if nc -w 5 -z host port && nc -w 5 -z host port`.

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner: I added that to my answer in case OP wanted that.

Comment: Thanks, should be: if nc -w 5 -z $host $port && nc -w 5 -z $host $port